# Good performance metrics API?

Tags: java, performance, api, metrics

I'm working on writing an API for gathering performance metrics in a Java application. These will consist of somewhat arbitrary things, but for now I'll mostly be gathering & recording run times of various parts of the application & other counts.

Are there any good performance metric APIs that handle a wide variety of gathered metrics? Any language is fine. I'm looking for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled across [Metrics](https://github.com/codahale/metrics), which may be something like what you're looking for.

(Disclaimer: I'm not a Java developer, so I haven't tried it out.)

Answer (score 0):

You should look [satoris community edition from jinspired](http://www.jinspired.org/satoris), they have open sourced their OpenAPI which is a mature API that has been built over the years in their commercial offering.